# Converting bitmasks from c# to Python (if statement)

Tags: c#, python, bitmask

I'm newbie in Python and I'm currently converting my project from C#. Is there anyone who can help me with getting this done properly?

```cs
// code for C#
if ( (number ^ 4u) > 0u) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: there is no unsigned ints in python....

Answer (score 1):

The `u` after the number, just means `unsigned`. Python does not have unsigned integers.

`^` means [`Logical exclusive OR operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) (`XOR`) however in this case I think you could just use:

```
if(number != 4):
    //do whatever
```

Is this coming from a decompiler? It is a very unusual way of writing a conditional statement for a human...

Answer (score 0):

Since  there is no unsigned ints in python....

```
if (number | 4) > 0 :
    // do something
```